# DebounceClickDirective on button click in typescript file

Tags: angular, typescript, debouncing

I have a problem regarding the debounce click on a button that I add via typescript, I don't know the correct syntax to make it work, pls help

```js
    private _initActionsFooter(): void {
        this.actionsFooterService.add([
            {
                label: 'AMBUSH.SHARED.FOOTER.HISTORY',
                click: () =>
                    this.dialogService.open(DialogHistoryAmbushComponent, {
                        context: {ambush: this.ambush}
                    }),
                outline: true,
                position: 'left',
                class: ['mr-3']
            },
            {
                label: 'AMBUSH.SHARED.FOOTER.DOCUMENTS',
                click: () => {
                    this.router.navigate([
                        'appostamenti',
                        this.route.snapshot.data.ambush.id,
                        'documenti'
                    ]);
                },
                outline: true,
                position: 'left',
                class: ['ml-3']
            },
            {
                label: 'AMBUSH.SHARED.FOOTER.REFRESH',
                click : () => this._save,
                disabled:
                    this.accessChecker.isGranted('view', 'only-view-atc') ||
                    this.ambushTabsStoreService.allFormsInvalid$,
                position: 'center',
                icon: 'save-outline',
            }
        ]);
        if (this.ambush?.fixedCabinOverId) {
            this.service
                .getDetail(this.ambush.fixedCabinOverId)
                .pipe(
                    catchError(() => {
                        return of(null);
                    })
                )
                .subscribe((res: Ambush) => {
                    this.cancellationReason = res.cancellationReason.value;
                });
        }
    }
```

here are the buttons, in particular I would need to use the function on the button
label: 'AMBUSH.SHARED.FOOTER.REFRESH'

this is my directive's file ,
I have made this file available throughout the application

```js
import {
  Directive,
  EventEmitter,
  HostListener,
  OnInit,
  Output
} from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDebounceClick]'
})
export class DebounceClickDirective implements OnInit {
  @Output() debounceClick = new EventEmitter();
  private clicks = new Subject();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clicks
      .pipe(debounceTime(500))
      .subscribe(e => this.debounceClick.emit(e));
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  clickEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.clicks.next(event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debounce is much easier than you think...:) and you don't need rxjs in your directive

Basically, when you type something, or move your mouse...you clear your timeout

But if you stop event a while, you don't clear your timeout so your function go ahead...

1- set your timeout in a variable

```
let timeoutId: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>
```

2- clear your timeout or leave it

```
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  clickEvent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // each time you click you clear the one second timeout
    clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      // do you stuff
    }, 1000)
```